# Squelching TensorFlow gRPC log messages

Tags: tensorflow, grpc

Whenever I create a distributed TF session (by specifying a nonempty target), the following log message gets printed:

```
E0104 11:24:54.243533559   17805 ev_epoll1_linux.c:1051]     grpc epoll fd: 19
```

For some reason, this is printed with ERROR log level, but the [corresponding line](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.8.0/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll1_linux.cc#L95) in gRPC code seems to be printing at INFO level (which would by default be invisible as desired). The [Swift implementation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/blob/master/Sources/CgRPC/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll1_linux.c#L1070) does log at ERROR level. I am on a Linux platform, so whatever version of gRPC the precompiled TF binary was using must be using an out-of-date gRPC version that prints to ERROR.

This suffices to replicate with TF 1.4.0 and 1.4.1, maybe others too.

```
python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__); tf.Session(tf.train.Server.create_local_server().target)'
```

Again looking at the [gRPC log source](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.8.0/src/core/lib/support/log.cc#L68), it appears that the `GRPC_VERBOSITY` environment variable should allow me to silence this error. However, trying any of `GRPC_VERBOSITY=FATAL`, `GRPC_VERBOSITY=0`, and `GRPC_VERBOSITY=-1` fails to help. This tells me that TF is probably launching the gRPC server with its own manually-set env vars. How do I override?

Answer (score 1):

grpc logged that message as ERROR before it was downgraded to INFO in Aug. 2017. I think tf is updating the grpc version.

Comment: Do you have a link for the update of grpc in TF? If it will be INFO then by default it won't print, which would be great. Also, why wouldn't the env variable work?